# Getting NullPointerException When Using saveRDS() in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a `NullPointerException` when trying to use the predict function on a saved rda model, note that when I use the model directly without saving it first it works perfectly, it is only when I use the saved model using the `saveRDS()` function and then call the model using `readRDS()` that I get this error.

the full error:

```
Error in .jcall("RWekaInterfaces", "[D", "distributionForInstances", .jcast(classifier,  : 
  java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here's the code:

```
training_1<-read.table("/data/CHURN_FILES/training_1.txt", sep="|", header=TRUE)

Model<- train(
  x = subset(training_1, select = -c(Subs_Id,Churn_flag_OUT,Value_Segment,
                                     Global_Profile
  )), y = training_1$Churn_flag_OUT,
  metric = "ROC" ,
  method = "LMT",
  trControl = myControl)


saveRDS(Hichem_Model, "/data/CHURN_FILES/Model.rda")
Model_2 <- readRDS("/data/CHURN_FILES/Model.rda")

My_Data$predict <- predict(Model_2 ,(subset(My_Data, 
                                                           select = -c(Subs_Id,Churn_flag_OUT,Value_Segment,
                                                                       Global_Profile))) , type = "prob")[,"churn"]
```

Comment: top of my head `.rda` files are meant for `load()`. `.RDS` files files are for `readRDS()`. you can try changing extensions and try again.

Comment: I did that and had the same problem.

Comment: A reproducible example with data will help anyone to better help you.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the data here, the data is huge anyway, note that I have tried this with another model on different data and it worked perfectly, however it doesn't seem to work with this particular model which is trained on a bigger amount of data.

Comment: I was hoping someone had ran into the same problem before and knows a detour around it, these are the only posts on the internet I found that have the same error trace, and as expected they all have no replies. I'm starting to think this is just an unfixed bug with the one of the libraries. the posts: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/RWeka-quot-java-lang-NullPointerException-quot-td3017851.html , https://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e12/help/10/10/3267.html , https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg114968.html

Comment: If its super critical for you, try without caret but rather using RWeka. `trControl` is simple to implement. ROC you can get later as well.

Comment: Also for that bigger model thing I hope JVM size is not playing bad there.